# Google geocode api limits

Tags: google-maps

I am utilizing the Google Maps API to obtain driving directions to several locations on one page.  There are JQuery selectors on the page where a user can select a different locations and view the driving directions for that location.

I am loading all of the requests on page load and I seem to be hitting a limit when I load more than 10 where it reports the remaining addresses cannot be found.  I'm assuming there's a limit of 10 per second or something like that.

Does anybody have any more information about this, and ways to get around it besides subscribing to the premier service?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Geocoding service is subject to daily limits per ip address (client) and a maximum request rate, which is probably what's causing the issue for you.

Here is a discussion from this morning on the rates of various services:
[Geocoding Services - limits - Google vs Yahoo vs others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346445/geocoding-services-limits-google-vs-yahoo-vs-others/4346518#4346518)

But you will probably find this article/sample from Google more helpful (See the timing Geocoding Requests section):
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlgeocode.html

Basically the concept is to add a delay between your requests and to increase that delay each time you receive an error message.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer seems to be:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat#quota-limits

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the usage limits are different (lower) when using the javascriptV3 api than when using the web services api directly.  I have been getting 'over usage limit' errors from the javascript api at rates as low as 1/s after the first 10 requests or so.  The javascript api is determining this on the client side, as the only results showing up in the chrome network panel are successful requests.  changing my code to use the web services directly for geocoding (and enabling that specific api in the api console) worked great for me.